# How do I store URL fragments in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, url, hierarchy

How are URLs (fragments) stored in a relational database?

In the following URL fragment:

```
 ~/house/room/table
```

it lists all the information on a table, and perhaps some information about the table.

This fragment:

```
~/house
```

outputs: `Street 13` and `Room, Garage, Garden`

```
~/house/room
```

outputs: `My room` and `Chair, Table, Window`

What does the Database schema looks like? What if I rename `house` to `flat`?

#### Possible solution

I was thinking that I could create a hash for the URL and store it along with `parentID` and information. If I rename some upper-level segment I would then need to update all the rows which contain the given segment.

Then I thought would store each segment along with information and its level:

```
SELECT FROM items WHERE key=house AND level=1 AND key=room AND level=2
```

How do I solve this problem if the URL can be arbitrarily deep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check **The Adjacency List Model** and **The Nested Set Model** described in *Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties*

you should find plenty information to this topic. one article is [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

**Update**

The **Nested Set Model** is very good if you are looking for a task like *'Retrieving a Single Path'*. What you have is *'Find the Immediate Subordinates of a Node'*. Here the **Adjacency List Model** is better.

```
| id | p_id | name  |
|  1 | null | root  |
|  2 |    1 | nd1.1 |
|  3 |    2 | nd1.2 |
|  4 |    1 | nd2.1 |
```

SQL to get a row with name of a fragment and it's direct sub items.

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    c.name
    SEPARATOR '/'
  ) AS subList
FROM _table p
INNER JOIN _table c
  ON p.id = c.p_id
WHERE p.name = 'root'
```

P.S. prefer `WHERE p.id = 1`. Id is unique where as name can be ambiguous.

see MySQL [GROUP CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for more syntax details.

Comment: Thanks, I read that article. However, what I don't get is how to find out which rows correspond to "/house/room/table"..? What if there is another path, say "/house/garage/table"? There are two different tables, as they are in different places...

Comment: @Lars: the example I liked is "/electronics/televisions/lcd"..."

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. He has a row and wants the path to it. I have a path and want a row.

Comment: if you have seleced the fragments you can concat them to a list. `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL or ``LISTAGG` in Oracle are ideas...

Comment: If I have URL which has 10 fragments, do I have to query the DB 10 times? Because, at first, all I have is the URL..?

Comment: Many DBMS can do this in one query but solutions are very specific per DBMS. What's your target DHMS?

Comment: sorry my thoughts where caught in the *'Retrieving a Single Path'* topic. just now really joined to your *'Find the Immediate Subordinates of a Node'* problem. Edited my Answer now with hopefully usable SQL ;-)